# Adding a google map in my rails app- need help getting started without using a Gem - would like to write custom code

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, google-maps

I have a rails app with a database of listings:addresses with coordinates in it. Currently Im showing the listings on the homepage as the app loads using the index method:

```
<h1>Listings</h1>

<table>
  <tr>
    <th>id</th>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Phone Number</th>
    <th>Latitude</th>
    <th>Longitude</th>
    <th>Cuisine</th>
  </tr>

<% count = 0 %>
<% @listings.each do |listing| %>

 <!--<%count = count.to_i + 1 %> -->
  <tr>
    <td><%= listing.id %></td>
    <td><%= listing.name %></td>
    <td><%= listing.telephone %></td>
    <td><%= listing.latitude %></td>
    <td><%= listing.longitude %></td>
    <td><%= listing.cuisine %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Details', listing %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_listing_path(listing) %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Delete', listing, confirm: 'Are you sure?', method: :delete %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Around', around_listings_path(:latitude => listing.latitude, :longitude => listing.longitude) %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Menus', %></td>
    </tr>
<% end %>
</table>


<br />

<%= link_to 'New Listing', new_listing_path %>


<br/>
    <%= debug(params) if Rails.env.development? %>
    <br/>
```

What Id like to do is add a new page which shows the listings on a map. Any suggestions on where to start? I'm not very familiar with Javascript, which I think I might have to know right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, why are you using latitude and longitude? I would not have a good opinion of a page on which I would have to enter those details about my listings.

That said, let me explain the simplest way of using Google Maps.

Just use the image tag with this link as a `src`

`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=#{address}&zoom=14&size=300x300&markers=#{address}&sensor=false`

Where `address` is `51+Wall+St, NY`, or whichever it is. You just have to substitute spaces to pluses in the address. Note that I'm also using markers, with `&markers=`, to mark the position of the marker.

Now about that javascript, you probably want to change the image when address changes (or latitude or longitude).

That's simple to accomplish with jQuery.

Let's say your map image is this `<img id="map_image" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=51+Wall+Street,NY&zoom=14&size=300x300&sensor=false"/>`.

Just change the `src` of `img` if some text input for address changes

```
$('input#listing_address').live('change',function(){
address = $(this).val().replace(/ /g,"+");
$('#map_image').attr("src","https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=" + address + "&zoom=14&size=300x200&sensor=false");
});
```

Comment: thanks for your response. Im showing the latitide and longitude on that page because Im just using that url as a data dump for my database, its only for development purposes. For production my index page will be the google map, with all the listings from my database shown as markers on it. So my question with this approach in mind is:Can I use your code above to show multiple markers on the google map? that is can I iterate over all the rows of my database and show each entry as a marker on the google maps. Is that the most efficient way to load my page. wouldnt this increase latency?

Answer (score 1):

Using gmaps4rails, it's pretty straight forward:

In a controller:

```
def yourmap
  @json = YourModel.all.to_gmaps4rails
end
```

In your view:

```
<%= gmaps({"markers" => {"data" => @json , "auto_adjust"=>false, }}} ) %>
```

There's a bit more to it than what I've shown,  but just to illustrate the basic concept of using gmaps4rails!  YourModel will have to have lat and lon attributes added.